# How to put selected items from a CheckBox Dialog in a list?

Tags: android, list, checkbox, dialog

I want to know how to store a selected item from a dialog witch check boxes in a list? As you can see bellow I have the dialog up and running but I cant figure out how to store the checked items in a LIST. I am not sure which is better a list or ArrayList so if you have any suggestions about that too please tell me.

```
final String[] typeOfTransport = 
        {
            "Bus",
            "Pedestrian",
            "Car",
            "Tram",
            "Bicycle",            
        };  
    final boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean[typeOfTransport.length];
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Select your transport:");
    dialogBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(typeOfTransport, itemsChecked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            itemsChecked[which] = isChecked;                 
        }           
    });

    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            String selectetdVal = " ";
            for (int i = 0; i < typeOfTransport.length; i++) 
            {  
                   if (itemsChecked[i]) 
                   {  
                     selectetdVal = selectetdVal + typeOfTransport[i]+ " ";
                     itemsChecked[i]=false;
                   }
        }   
            //textBox2.setText(selectetdVal);               
            Toast.makeText(MainWindow.this, selectetdVal,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs, List is an interface.
You already have an array with your checked items isn't it ?

```
Object[] array = new Object[]{"12","23","34"};
java.util.List list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Comment: yeah but wouldn't that just put all the values from array to the list? I want to put just the selected items not all of them.

Comment: Just loop your array and if the item is checked then add it yo your list.